# Given the basis vectors of two linear vector spaces, how can I determine if one of the vector spaces is a subspace of the other?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I know the basis vectors of a linear vector space $X=\{x_i\}$ and another linear vector space $Y=\{y_j\}$. It is not obvious if either of these sets is contained in the other. How can I determine if one of these vector spaces is the subspace of the other?

Comment: Check if each $x_i$ can be written as finite linear combinations of the $y_j$s (and viceversa)

Comment: @Rahat Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

A possible way, for a more general result, is to find the basis for each one and find the intersection or, to determine if one is a subspace of the other, consider the RREF to check the linear dependence.